# Passing Model to Controller from View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on my first application in ASP.NET MVC and have run into a snag that I cannot figure out, even after reading the entire internet.

So I have several Views (they are reports) that are created with View Models, which are populated based on user selection criteria. I'm trying to build a method that accepts a Model and exports it in Excel format (using EPPlus), but the Model needs to be sent from one of these Views. This is somewhat of a functional/usability, rather than a technical requirement. A user can run reports, and after viewing the report, can click a button/link and an Excel version of the report they're looking at will be created. I want to pass the Model that the View that's being displayed is based on since the work has already been done to build this specific View Model based on the user's report selection criteria.

This is all fine and good, and I can successfully pass a Model from a View that's displaying a report to the method that builds the report. All of the data in the View Model I pass seems to be there, except a collection of Models (IEnumerable) that is part of it. <--That is where I'm stuck. The collection of IEnumerable has 0 items in it at breakpoint, but this is definitely not the case in when the View Model is created and passed into the View initially.

I'm stuck--please help.

**View Model:**

```
public class ReportViewModel
{

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project #")]
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SystemModel> SelectedSystems { get; set; }//has items when created and passed into the View intially, but not when the Model is passed from the View to the method/controller. 

    [Display(Name = "All Systems")]
    public bool AllSystems { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "In Progress Systems")]
    public bool InProgressSystems { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Completed Systems")]
    public bool CompletedSystems { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unchecked Systems")]
    public bool UncheckedSystems { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Systems with Problems - Ours")]
    public bool JciIssue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Systems with Problems - Other's")]
    public bool OtherIssue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Include Points with Problems")]
    public bool IncludePoints { get; set; }

}
```

**View:**

```
    @model ProjectOps_5.ViewModels.ReportViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Software Cx Status Report";
}

<h2>Software Cx Status Report</h2>

<div>
    <div>
        <hr />

 @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportExcel", Model)//call to method

//the report
```

**Method:**

```
    public void ExportExcel(ReportViewModel model)
        {
           //make Excel file
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot pass a model that contains properties that are either complex objects or collections to a GET. Internally the `ActionLink()` method calls the `.ToString()` method of each property so basicaly the `DefaultModelBinder` is trying to set the property to as follows

```
model.SelectedSystems = "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SystemModel>";
```

which of course fails and the property is `null`.

Fortunately it does not work, or you would generate a really ugly query string and could easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

Instead, pass the `ProjectId` property (I'm assuming that uniquely identifies the object) and get the model again in the `ExportExcel()` method

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportExcel", new { ID = Model.ProjectId })
```

and in the controller

```
public void ExportExcel(int ID)
{
  // Get your ReportViewModel based on the ID and do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that info, that explains a lot. However, the Model.ProjectId won't get the SystemModels that I need, since to create the IEnumerable<SystemModel> SelectedSystems I've already ran through a mess of if then else, loops, etc. That's the main reason I'm trying to reuse this list and not have to run that code again. Maybe it's not that big of a deal to run it again, but I would have to think about how pass all of the selection/filtering criteria from the original report selection.

Comment: Not enough detail to be sure of what you need to do, but of course you can always pass additional route values that define your filter/order/etc in the `ActionLink()`

Comment: So in other words there will be a lot more SystemModels under a ProjectModel than what I need to include in the given report.

Comment: OK, I'll think about that. I suppose I could pass the Id of all SystemModels I need but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: Is there some property of `SystemModels` that you can pass to the method in addition to the ProjectId that can be used to filter the results you need for the report? You could always consider storing the collection in `Session` before you generate the view, and then in the`ExportExcel()` method, read the collection from session.

Comment: I don't know about Session yet but it sounds like something to look into. Need to shut down for the night. Thank you

Comment: All I can do is give the answer to the question as it is :). Suggest you do some research and then ask a new question if your having issues

Answer (score 1):

Passing the whole view model to another method is probably not the best idea since you don't know the size of the model (the number of elements in `SelectedSystems`). If it is too large you may exceed the max request length or make the user wait too long until the request completes.

But if you're absolutely sure this is what you need - it can be done using a form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportExcel", null, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("ProjectId", Model.ProjectId)
        @Html.Hidden("ProjectName", Model.ProjectName)
        ...
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedSystems.Count(); i++)
        {
            var systemModel = Model.SelectedSystems.ElementAt(i);
            @Html.Hidden("SelectedSystems[" + i + "].Property1", systemModel.Property1)
            @Html.Hidden("SelectedSystems[" + i + "].Property2", systemModel.Property2)
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Export to Excel" />
    }
```

However, a better approach would be to use some identificators of all the objects you want to export (not sure what they might be in your case) and pass those IDs as `ActionLink` route values.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below logic , that you have to do before sending the request(or depends on your page, but it should be available before sending the request)

```
var html = "";
for (index = 0; index < SelectedSystems.length; index++) {
    html += '<input type="hidden" name="SelectedSystems[' + index + '].PropertyName" id="SelectedSystems _' + index + '_PropertyName" value="YourValue"/>';
}
$("#divSelectedSystems").html(html); //Here divSelectedSystems is one dummy div with that id
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate/clarify?

Comment: I mean if it is collection properties then you have to add hidden field for each record and for each properties with Index, so i hope you want to pass data for property IEnumerable<SystemModel> SelectedSystems so for first record you have to add 1 hidden field(taking for 1 field) like <input type="hidden"  name="SelectedSystems[0].PropertyName" id="SelectedSystems_0_PropertyName" /> for 2nd record <input type="hidden"  name="SelectedSystems[1].PropertyName" id="SelectedSystems_1_PropertyName" /> and it should be in you page binded so you can loop in javascript and add in any empty div.

Comment: Let me know if you still didn't understand