# asp.net mvc view passed null model to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried solutions from threads:

- [ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)
- [Passing Model to Controller from View in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110271/passing-model-to-controller-from-view-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [MVC4 Passing model from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339398/mvc4-passing-model-from-view-to-controller)

but there is still no solution for my problem. My code seems to be fine

the view (DodajWpis):

```
@model mvc.Models.WpisModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddedNew", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("Title")
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.title)

    @Html.Label("Description")
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.descr)

    @Html.Label("Priority")
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.priority)

    @Html.Label("Deadline")
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.deadline)

   <input type="submit" />
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddNew()
{
    WpisModel wpis = new WpisModel();
    return View("DodajWpis",wpis);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddedNew(WpisModel model)
{
    return null;
}
```

and model

```
public class WpisModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string descr;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string title;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public int priority;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime deadline;
}
```

I'm receiving an empty model from my view. I also tried to bind it (via [this article, "Registering Model Binders" section](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios)) but i can't add code "Bind(Allowed= " and i'm stuck at it. Can someone take a look and help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields. You need to make them properties (add `{ get; set; }` so their values can be **set**

Comment: you're right. thank you